# Rails 3.1 and selecting out across three tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following and am trying to figure out how to select the User info (sql at end of question).

```
# only global_id and list_id
class GlobalList < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name :globals_lists
    belongs_to :list
end

# user_id
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :global_lists
    belongs_to :user
end

# email
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
end
```

How would I select out the emails of the user list assuming I have a global_id (ie assuming a global_id of 256,

```
select u.* from users u, lists l, globals_lists gl where gl.global_id=256 and gl.list_id=l.id and l.user_id=u.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`User.includes({:lists => :global_lists}).where(['global_lists.global_id = ?', 256])`

That will return `User` objects, which seems to be what you are looking for from your query. You can then get their email from their `.email` attribute, in a loop, or however you need it.

Comment: is there a good source / tutorial for showing these types of queries - I have a ton of these that I need to port from sql. thx

Comment: Yeah you can always go for `Object.find_by_sql(my_sql_string)` if your SQL is very specific.

Comment: agreed - I've done that in a few places. Will probably be a thing to refactor at a later poing